# Template method specialization linking error

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

Consider the following header and source files:

```
// main.cpp
#include "myClass.h"

int main()
{
  MyClass m;
  m.foo<double>();
  m.foo<float>();
}
```

---

```
// myClass.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:

  template <typename T>
  void foo()
  {
    cout << "Template function<T> called" << endl;
  }

  template <>
  void foo<int>()
  {
    cout << "Template function<int> called" << endl;
  }

  template <>
  void foo<float>();

};
```

---

```
// myClass.cpp
#include "myClass.h"

template <>
void MyClass::foo<float>()
{
  cout << "Template function<float> called" << endl;
}
```

I get a linking error wrt the `foo<float>` specialization. If I place the definition of the specialization in the header file, then everything works as expected.

I figured that the reason may be that the method is not explicitly instantiated (although full specialization of `template class` does not need an explicit instantiation for proper linking). If I try to explicitly instantiate the method, I get this error:

> error C3416: 'MyClass::foo' : an explicit specialization may not be explicitly instantiated

**So the questions are:**

- Is there any way to define the specialization in the `cpp` file and link properly?
- If not, why not? I can explicitly instantiate template methods that
  are not specialized just fine. Why not the same for full specializations?

Comment: @billz: This is not a duplicate (or I am bad at searching... but I searched with my colleagues for quite some time). There are many questions regarding class specialization and `template function` specializations but not when the class is a non-template (does that matter?) and the `template method` is a full specialization.

Comment: @billz: With regards to your duplicate link, that is a general question about linking errors with templates. I am already aware of the tricks to explicitly instantiate a class template and template methods. The problem here is `full` specialization of a `template method`.

Comment: Shows how antiquated my toolchain is, apparently (Apple LLVM 4.1, which is *supposed* to be C++11 compliant), because the header file itself in this code won't compile for me; errors with ("Explicit specialization of 'foo' in class scope") on the first in-class specialization.

Comment: @WhozCraig Gcc 4.7.2 won't compile either but VS2012 compiles

Comment: @billz then I take back all the swearing I just launched in Apple's general direction.

Comment: I believe that it is not possible with C++03  to put the definition of a template (specialized or not) in a separate translation unit. Would you use C++11, that it would probably work by qualifying the declaration as `extern`. Please someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @didierc: It is definitely possible to put the definition of a template in a separate translation unit. All you need to do is explicitly instantiate it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4933205/368599 Incidentally, this is what is confusing me, hence the question. Why is the fully specialized template method exempt from such rules?

Comment: thanks, I wasn't aware of the distinction. What's the point of explicit instanciation, if there's no specialization?

Comment: nevermind, got the answer in the comments overthere.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although WhozCraig's answer (now deleted) provides the correct code to solve your problem, here are some direct answers to your questions, including comments on your code:

1. `foo<int>()` and `foo<float>()` are explicit specializations of a member template. Those must not appear inside the definition of the class they belong to. The Standard says:

   > (§14.7.3/3) [...] The deﬁnition of a class or class template shall precede the declaration of an explicit specialization for a member template of the class or class template. [...]

   So you must put them after the class definition.
2. In the case of `foo<int>`, which is fully defined in the header file, this implies that you must put the word `inline` before the definition; otherwise you will get into trouble with the linker if the header file is included in more than one translation unit.
3. The specialization for `foo<float>()` is defined in a separate file that is later linked to `main.cpp`. This is possible, but it requires that a declaration of it be given in the header file (you do this already, but you must do it outside the class definition):

   ```
     template <>
     void MyClass::foo<float>();
   ```

   This is required because of another statement in the Standard:

   > (§14.7.3/6) If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the ﬁrst use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required. [...]
4. Since all specializations are *explicit* (i.e. full specializations, to use your word), there is no need for explicit instantiations, but they are possible (§14.7.2). You would place them at the end of the .cpp file, and the syntax would be:

   ```
   template void MyClass::foo<float>();
   template void MyClass::foo<int>();
   ```

   Again, this is only really useful for types that do *not* have their own explicit specializations.

The correct code for the header and implementation file therefore looks like this:

.h file:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  template <typename T> void foo()
  { cout << "Template function<T> called" << endl; }
};

template <> inline void MyClass::foo<int>()
{ cout << "Template function<int> called" << endl; }

template <> void MyClass::foo<float>();
```

.cpp:

```
#include "myClass.h"

template <> void MyClass::foo<float>()
{ cout << "Template function<float> called" << endl; }

/* This is unnecessary for float, but may be useful for
   types that do not have their own explicit specializations: */
template void MyClass::foo<float>();
```

Comment: +1. *thank you*. #4 was the part I was totally brain-farting on. I couldn't understand the need to do with the given preconditions. I was pretty sure the rest was ok. This is a solid answer and the standard cites make it much more apropos for the question, so I'm going to drop my answer entirely and favor this. Remove my reference from the body at your leisure. I'm just happy I wasn't thinking off the deep end.

Comment: Great answer, explains everything! Thanks! (+1)

Comment: In the second to last code sample, shouldn't that be `MyClass::f...` instead of just `f` for the ones outside the class body?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Definitely -- thanks for pointing this out. I've corrected it now.