# Why do I have to include the implementation file in class derived from a template class?

Tags: c++

Simple question - why do I have to `#include "listType.cpp"` or get linker errors here? Why can't I just include the header?

stockListType.h:

```
#ifndef stockListType_H
#define stockListType_H

#include "listType.h"
#include "stockType.h"
#include "listType.cpp"

using namespace std;

class stockListType : public listType<stockType>
{
private:
    unique_ptr<int[]> sortIndicesByGainLoss;

public:
    void sortByStockSymbol();
    void sortByGainLoss();

    stockListType(int maxSize);
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because in a traditional C++ compiler approach template code "doesn't exist" as a "material execution entity" until it's instantiated for some "real" types (`stockType` in your case). There're however techniques called `explicit instantiation` which allows to to specify during processing of "listType.cpp" that later you will need an instance of the code for e.g. `stockType`, `otherType` and `int`. Read from this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by56e477.aspx or this: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/14272/ or this: [How do I explicitly instantiate a template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933056/how-do-i-explicitly-instantiate-a-template-function)

Also another reason for using a source, not pre-compiled code of template classes and functions is that it's possible to override *later* an implementation of a given template class, method or function for a particular template argument (recall the famous `std::cout << "Hello, World " << 1 << MyClassObject << std::endl`, that's the classical case when `operator<<(ostream&, T&)` is defined for each particular type separately.

Besides, if you take a look into standard C++ STL library (e.g. `<vector>` or `<string>`) you will see that the whole code of the classes is right in header files, or files included from header files (`.tcc`) even a rather complex one (see `Boost.Spirit`, well, if you're brave enough :) ). That's because it's not possible to create an executable code for vector until vector elements (`stockType` etc) are defined.