# Declare function template instantiation without the template

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to declare that a symbol is an explicit instantiation of a function template, without defining the function template first?

It would express to the compiler that there exists a function template in another translation unit that is instantiated somewhere, and we want to call the instantiated function.

```
// declaration of instantiation, perhaps it would look like one of these:
// template<typename> void foo(int);
// template<typename> void foo<int>(int);

void bar(int i) {
    // definition of function unknown to caller, it shouldn't matter
    foo(i);

    // either that or this perhaps:
    foo<int>(i);
}
```

Is there a technical reason this can't be done or is it just for lack of syntax? Is there a reason that it's not possible to provide sufficient information in a declaration to generate calls to an instantiated function template?

There is no Y behind this X. This question is meant literally. It's an abstract question about the C++ language. I could provide an example that doesn't compile but that would just be a distraction.

The question is also not about specialization per se. Whether the template was specialized shouldn't matter. This question is only concerned with declaring that a template exists and that it was instantiated.

Related question: [How do I explicitly instantiate a template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933056/how-do-i-explicitly-instantiate-a-template-function) - however that does not solve this problem, as it requires the full template definition to be visible.

Comment: What is the higher level goal you're trying to accomplish here?  You may need to be a bit more explicit with your examples--exactly what doesn't work?  I'm about 70% clear on what you're asking now.  :)

Comment: Note that declaring an explicit instantiation is redundant if you only need to call the function, e.g. this is correct and instantiates: `template<typename T> void foo(T t);  void bar() { foo(5); }`

Comment: @MattMcNabb I actually had a link to that question in the first draft of this question but thought it was extraneous.

Comment: Comments addressed in edit.

Comment: @MattMcNabb If this isn't possible then the question is why. The key part is that the template has been instantiated with known parameters.

Comment: @Praxeolitic I have edit the question with what your intent seems to be (sorry - did it in parallel to your latest edit) to clarify - if I have missed the mark then feel free to roll it back

Comment: @MattMcNabb Looks good. (You clobbered my other parallel edit!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "extern template" here. It tells the compiler not to instantiate it in every translation units. This is part of C++11 enhancements. For example, we may declare the template in a header file a.hpp as

```
// a.hpp
template <class T>
T fun(T& a);
```

Then in a.cpp

```
// a.cpp
#include "a.hpp"
extern template int fun(int&);
int main()
{
   int a = 100;
   return fun(100);
}
```

And in b.cpp we can actually instantiate the template:

```
// b.cpp
#include "a.hpp"

template <>
int fun(int& x)
{
    return x + 1;
}
```

Comment: Neat. Seems to work with explicit instantiation too. But the template definition still must be visible. I don't understand why.

Comment: After experimenting: If you forward declare the template and make the extern template declaration, you don't need the template definition to be visible to the caller.

Comment: In `b.cpp` you have an explicit specialization of a `fun` function template not an instantiation. And explicit specialization should be declared before the first use of it so your code is ill-formed.

Comment: @Constructor yes. I just tried to explain the new enhancement where instantiation in every translation unit can be avoided with C++11 and was relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Nipun Talukdar's answer, there's no need for specialization or for the template definition to be visible to the caller.

a.cpp

```
template<class T> T fun(T);
extern template int fun(int);

int main() {
    // this works, even though we have no idea how fun() is defined
    fun(100);
    // this would fail to link
    // fun('a');
}
```

b.cpp

```
template<class T>
T fun(T x) {
    return x;
}

// explicit instantiation
template int fun<int>(int x);
```