# How to Return a Variable Type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, auto

I'm trying to write a `Config` class in C++, and I want syntax like `myConfig->get<ANYTYPE>(str key, ANYTYPE default)`; I've been playing around with templates, and I think I'm close, but I keep getting errors like:

```
// caused by config->get<bool>("fullscreen", false);
error: undefined reference to `bool const Config::get<bool>(char*, bool) const'
```

or

```
// caused by config->get<int>("width", 800);
error: undefined reference to `int const Config::get<int>(char*, int) const'
```

Here's the function declaration / definition for the above lines of code.

```
template<typename T>
const auto get(char* key, T def) const -> T
{
    T ret = _config[key].as<T>();

    if( ret )
        return ret;

    return def;
}
```

I come from a PHP / Laravel background, so I'm looking to create something similar to `Input::get("elName", "defaultValue");`

What do I have to do to get the above code to link properly?

Comment: Place the definition of the templated function in the header file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574417/845568)

Comment: Not related to your question but you should make the first parameters `char const*` to have it accept string literals. You may want to consider having an overload using a `std::string const&`, too.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious - woah: your suggestion to place the templated function in the header file worked; Can you post it as an answer (as well as why I couldn't split it into a .h/.cpp combo) so I can accept it?

Comment: Is it okay to keep this question and link to that answer? I wonder if it might be useful to break that question out into subparts because this is a specific use case, not a generic (... lol) question. Oh the irony.

Comment: I say that because I couldn't find that answer while I was googling. My thought process is that if someone finds this question (which is a little more targeted than the other), they would then be directed to the specific answer they need.

Comment: @Goldentoa11 I suspect the issue was more your search terms. Nothing about your issue is related to how to return a variable type from a function, but something like ["undefined reference to template function"](https://www.google.com/search?q=undefined+reference+to+template+function) will give you good hits (a few of which actually do lead to the linked duplicate). You must strengthen your search fu, grasshopper.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the template definition has to be available when you use it.

This means you must place the definition itself in the header file, rather than in a separate source file like you traditionally do with non template code. If you do not, then the code is not available to be generated when it is used, hence the error.

Alternatively, you can [explicitly instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4933205/616460) a useful set of types in a source file somewhere.