# Can I instantiate a template without repeating its signature?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, instantiation, decltype

I want to instantiate some function with a long signature:

```
template<typename T> void foo(
    T& t,
    SomeType some_parameter,
    AnotherType another_parameter,
    EtcType yet_another_parameter,
    AsYouCanTell this_is_a_very_long_signature);
```

The straightforward way to instantiate `foo` is:

```
template void foo<int>(
    int& t,
    SomeType some_parameter,
    AnotherType another_parameter,
    EtcType yet_another_parameter,
    AsYouCanTell this_is_a_very_long_signature);
```

but that's a duplication of the long signature. And what if I want specific instantiation for 5 different types - do I copy it 5 times? Doesn't make sense...

I was thinking maybe I could write

```
template decltype(foo<int>);
```

but for some reason this doesn't work. Can I make it work, somehow?

Comment: He is not trying to do any of those things. He is trying to explicitly instantiate this template.

Comment: You don't need the names of the function parameters, by the way: `template foo<int>(int&, SomeType, AnotherType, EtcType, AsYouCanTell);`. You can further shorten the type names by using type aliases.

Comment: I wonder whether you can abuse C++14's variable templates to do this: Instead of explicitly instantiating the function template, maybe an explicit instantiation of a variable template referring to the function template might be sufficient. Possibly, a similar thing could be achieved with static data members and alias templates, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can, indeed, instantiate your function without repeating its signature - but the syntax is a little different:

```
template
decltype(foo<int>) foo<int>;
```

`decltype` gives you a *type* but the explicit instantiation requires a *declaration*  which is a type followed by a name.

Tried with GCC 4.9.1; it works as expected and compiles without any warnings even with the `-pedantic` flag.

Comment: @dyp I'm not a language lawyer.  I admit that I have found this solution mostly by chance and was happy GCC accepted it.  I'd be interested to hear what the standards has to say about it, though.

Comment: And this answer provides the expected compiler error if you haven't provided an implementation: (clang 3.5.0) `error: explicit instantiation of undefined function template 'foo'`. I had tried another solution of my own, but it gives me only linker errors when the implementation is missing.

Comment: I am reluctant to say that this is entirely legal because of [dcl.fct]/12 *"A typedef of function type may be used to declare a function but shall not be used to define a function."* But I think that although the statement in the answer is an *explicit instantiation definition*, I don't think it counts as the definition of a function wrt [dcl.fct]/12.

Comment: @dyp That rule cross references [dcl.fct.def], and the grammar in [dcl.fct.def.general]/p1 basically says that it must have a body or `=default;` or `=delete;` to count as a function definition.

Comment: So what happens if there is another unrelated `template<typename> void foo(args)` with another signature (cf [Mooing Duck's argument](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28356131/1023390))?

Comment: This works with gcc and clang, sadly not with MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/Gb7vaa3We

Answer (score 4):

It's actually even simpler than @5gon12eder suggested:

```
template decltype(foo<int>) foo;
```

but yes, it's just like he said - `decltype()` only provides the type, and a signature is not really a type.

**Edit:** This doesn't work when the template has value arguments rather than just types, so if we have

```
template <typename T, unsigned Val> bar(T t);
```

then

```
template decltype(bar<int, 1>) bar;
```

will not compile, while

```
template decltype(bar<int, 1>) bar<int, 1>;
```

will.

Comment: I'm surprised that this works.  Does it mean the types are deduced for the second `foo`?  That's cool.

Comment: @dyp But it has to be compiled as the mangled name for the correct template instantiation or the linker can't find the definition.  I have looked at the assembly code and it reads the exact same whether or not the `<int>` is provided.

Comment: @dyp The template arguments clearly have to be deduced from the type.

Comment: @Columbo I am currently not sure if this is legal at all. But as far as I can tell, this follows the strange `using my_func_t = void(int); my_func_t my_func_name;` syntax.

Comment: @dyp Why would this not be legal? It is ill-formed NDR to implicitly instantiate a template in an explicit instantiation? :o) (In all seriousness, I am currently checking the rules.)

Comment: @Columbo Why would this cause implicit instantiation? The return type is not a placeholder, and the function template name only appears in an unevaluated context as an expression. I was worried that no template-id appears in that declaration, but it seems this is legal since `foo` is a template-name.

Comment: @5gon12eder Thinking about this again, you're right: The template arguments of `foo` are deduced from the types of the function parameters (which are specified via the `decltype(foo<int>)`). This is similar to `template void foo<int>(int);` vs `template void foo(int);`. The former will also work for the case `template void foo<int>();`, where deduction from the function parameter types is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good, legitimate use for a macro:

```
#define INSTANTIATE_FOO(type) \
    template void foo<type>(type& t, \
                  SomeType some_parameter, \
                  AnotherType another_parameter, \
                  EtcType yet_another_parameter, \
                  AsYouCanTell this_is_a_very_long_signature);

INSTANTIATE_FOO(int)
INSTANTIATE_FOO(float)
INSTANTIATE_FOO(my_little_dragon)

#undef INSTANTIATE_FOO
```

Comment: You're still duplicating the signature at least once - when defining the macro. And if you try to avoid the duplication, it becomes a convoluted macro...

Answer (score 1):

No, because of overloading

```
template<typename T> void foo(T& t,
                     SomeType some_parameter,
                     AnotherType another_parameter,
                     EtcType yet_another_parameter,
                     AsYouCanTell this_is_a_very_long_signature);
template<template T> void foo(T& t); //completely unrelated function
template<template T> void foo(char); //another completely unrelated function
```

Now imagine, what is the minimum information required to explicitly instantiate the first one?  Well, you need the full signature to disambiguate it, so

```
explicit int foo(int&, SomeType, AnotherType, EtcType, AsYouCanTell)
```

is the theoretical minimum amount of information.  So what C++ requires actually has very little overhead:

```
template void foo<int>(int& t, SomeType, AnotherType, EtcType, AsYouCanTell);
```

If you don't want to type all that, then Konrad's suggestion of a macro is the way to go.

Comment: But I don't have any of these overloaded functions.

Comment: The language has to use a format for explicit instantiation that would be valid _no matter_ what other functions exist.  Whether or not they actually exist is irrelevant.  They _could_ exist, and the syntax must support that.