# Using decltype with macro for explicit instantiation of class member functions

Tags: c++, templates, decltype

I am attempting to extend upon [Can I use decltype (or something similar) for explicit template instantiation without signature duplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355934/can-i-use-decltype-or-something-similar-for-explicit-template-instantiation-wi) for use with templated member functions, but I am having no luck. Current attempts at making this work look like:

```
// header
struct my_class
{
    template <typename T>
    some_type my_func(T val);
};

//source
template <typename T> 
some_type my_class::my_func(T val)
{
    ....
}

// attempt a
template decltype(my_class::my_func<int>) my_class::my_func<int>; 

// attempt b
template std::remove_pointer<decltype(&my_class::my_func<int>)>::type my_class::my_func<int>;
```

Is this possible? If so, any thoughts on how I can make this work?

EDIT:

so it appears that this requires some compiler update only available in clang or gcc 6.1+. The following code provided by @yakk will work for const methods:

```
template <class T>                                                                                                                                                                
struct pointer_to_member_function{};                                                                                                                                                                                

template <typename pmf_t> 
using pointer_to_member_signature
    = typename pointer_to_member_function<pmf_t>::signature;

template <class ret_t, class class_t, class...args>                                                                                                                               
struct pointer_to_member_function<ret_t(class_t::*)(args...) const>                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                                                 
     using signature = ret_t(args...) const;  
};
```

However, the following modification does compile across all const-ness:

```
template <class function_t, class class_t>                                                                                                                               
struct pointer_to_member_function<function_t class_t::*>                                                                                                               
{                                     
   using signature = function_t;                                                                                                                                             
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this is standard compliant, but it works in clang:

```
template<class Pmf>
struct pmf_sig{};
template<class Pmf>
using pmf_sig_t=typename pmf_sig<Pmf>::type;
template<class R, class T, class...Args>
struct pmf_sig<R(T::*)(Args...)>{
  using type=R(Args...);
};
```

then `const` and `const&` and `&&` support:

```
template<class R, class T, class...Args>
struct pmf_sig<R(T::*)(Args...) const>{
  using type=R(Args...) const;
};
template<class R, class T, class...Args>
struct pmf_sig<R(T::*)(Args...) const&>{
  using type=R(Args...) const&;
};
template<class R, class T, class...Args>
struct pmf_sig<R(T::*)(Args...) const&&>{
  using type=R(Args...) const&&;
};
template<class R, class T, class...Args>
struct pmf_sig<R(T::*)(Args...) &&>{
  using type=R(Args...) &&;
};
template<class R, class T, class...Args>
struct pmf_sig<R(T::*)(Args...) &>{
  using type=R(Args...) &;
};
```

The use:

```
template<> pmf_sig_t<decltype(&my_class::my_func<int>)> my_class::my_func<int>;
```

Or:

```
template pmf_sig_t<decltype(&my_class::my_func<int>)> my_class::my_func<int>;
```

The idea is that `my_class::` is not part of the signature in some sense.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7654f7ef06956fe).

Comment: this works for non-const member function but falls apart when const qualified. I havent had any luck with a const specialization. thoughts?

Comment: it appears that this only works for clang and gcc 6.1+? What's the missing language requirement here for lesser gcc versions? see https://godbolt.org/g/kWWP7p

Comment: @mgoldman Uncertain.  I was aware that variations on this technique worked (in a different context), so I suggested trying it here; I am unaware of the basis of this technique in the standard.