# explicit instantiation of function using decltype : work on g++ but not on Visual C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-instantiation

This codes [run on G++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a509dd1f907d567), but [not on Visual C++](https://rextester.com/KRAGN35032).

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T> void foo( T& t,int some_parameter){}
template decltype(foo<int>) foo;
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

Here is the error from Visual C++ :-

> error C2206: 'foo': typedef cannot be used for function definition

**Incentive :** I don't want to repeat function signature for explicit instantiation.
I modified code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28356212 .

Which one is wrong?  How to workaround it in Visual C++?

### Current indirect workaround

A day later, here is the best workaround I found : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350144 .

```
#include <tuple>
template<typename... Ts>auto instantiate() {
    static auto funcs = std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(
        foo1<Ts>,
        foo2<Ts>
    )...);
    return &funcs;
}
template auto instantiate<int, double>();
```

However, in Visual C++, it works only when compile `foo.cpp` with optimization turned on :-

- `Custom` or `Disabled(/Od)` is not OK.
- Use all of `/O1`, `/O2` and `/Ox`   are OK.
- Without any of `/Od`, `/O1`, `/O2` and `/Ox` :-

  - Just `/Og` is OK.
  - Just `/Oi`, `/Ot`, `/Oy`, `/Ob2`, `/GF` and `/Gy` is not OK.
  - Use all flags in the two above lines is OK.

**Workaround of the workaround** (work with `/Od`): Call the `std::tuple_size<decltype(instantiate<int, double>())>` inside a dummy function in a .cpp.  Then declare the dummy function in header.

Comment: it can not work that way - what should happen if you have more than one foo?

Comment: @Bernd  Compile error?  Let's say I care only the situation that there is only one `foo` in the universe.

Comment: `template<> decltype(foo<int>) foo;`?

Comment: More handy link: https://godbolt.org/z/1nx3cf

Comment: why there is `template` in front of `decltype(foo<int>) foo;`?

Comment: @Marek R  :: Thanks for the better link.  Sorry, I don't know the reason, so I can't answer yours.

Comment: @B0FEE664 :: Thanks, it is now compilable in VC.  I will test if it really instantiates the function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe msvc is wrong. In short, an explicit instantiation is simply a `template` followed by your typical declaration.

If you follow the grammar [[temp.explicit]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.explicit#2)

```
explicit-instantiation:
    template declaration
declaration:
    block-declaration
block-declaration:
    simple-declaration
simple-declaration:
    decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list;
decl-specifier-seq:
    decl-specifier
decl-specifier:
    defining-type-specifier
defining-type-specifier:
    simple-type-specifier
simple-type-specifier:
    decltype-specifier
decltype-specifier:
    decltype ( expression )
```

I don't believe there is a work around for this. Apparently, msvc considers `decltype` as a type alias, and rejects any "perceived" definitions with signatures that are aliases. These are rejected as well

```
using F = decltype(foo<int>);
template F foo;
extern template F foo;  // not even a definition
```

Yet it accepts these

```
F bar;
decltype(foo<int>) baz;
```