# Invalid cast error in function template which return values depends on its generic type

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following function template

```
template<typename T>
T foo(){
    if(std::is_same<T,int>::value){
        return 1;
    }
    if(std::is_same<T,std::string>::value){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

I want to apply it like this:

```
int main(){
    std::cout << foo<int>() << std::endl;    // 1
    std::cout << foo<string>() << std::endl;    // "Hello"
}
```

If I try to compile my template the compiler throws the following error:
`error: cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'const char [6]'`.

If I remove the second `if` statement everything compiles fine and I get the correct output therefore I guess the comparison `std::is_same<T,int>::value` works as intended.

It seems like the Compiler detects the type of `T`, checks if all `return` statements match it and throws the error because an `std::string` is not implicitly castable to `int`.

Has anyone a solution or another workaround to satisfy my intention?

**EDIT**

To explain my intention: I am writing a wrapper class for a database cursor class. As these cursors are usually defined it has several member functions like `getInt()` or `getString()`. My idea was to implement a generic `get<T>()` that uses the corresponding cursor member function that depends on `T`.

Comment: In C++17 you will get `if constexpr` that allows some parts not to compile. Right now, all parts of the code must be valid for *all* possible type `T`. You will have to add separate overloads of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference `foo<int>`, the compiler generates a function like the following from your template:

```
int foo<int>(){
    if(true){
        return 1;
    }
    if(false){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Above code is ill-typed, because (as the compiler tells you) an `int` cannot be initialized with a C string (`char const [N]`). Sure, the corresponding `return` statement will never be reached, but that's something to be figured out by "dead code elimination", which is merely an optimization.

The solution "now" is shown in [Dustin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43219012/1116364), with C++17 we'll get `if constexpr` which is able to discard code paths the way you expected it:

```
template<typename T>
T foo(){
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T,int>::value){
        return 1;
    }
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T,std::string>::value){
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Forget the if statements and fully specialize the template function:

```
template<>
int foo<int>(){
    return 1;
}

template<>
std::string foo<std::string>(){
    return "Hello";
}
```

Comment: And to help understand why your original code didn't work, replace all the occurrences of `T` in your original template with `int`, which is essentially the result of invoking `foo<int>()`. Then it becomes clear that you have a function declared to return an `int` trying to return a `string`.

Comment: Note: It's not explicit instantiation, but rather template specialization. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4933205/1116364).

Comment: I should have said fully specialized... edited. Thank you

Comment: You don't need the angle brackets in `foo<int>` and `foo<string>`