# implicit instantiation of undefined template AND mutual header includes

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is the error I get from make:

```
In file included from ui/graphical/game/control/chatcommand/chatcommand.cpp:20:
ui/graphical/game/control/chatcommand/chatcommand.h:67:41: error: 
      implicit instantiation of undefined template 'cChatCommandParser<>'
        return cChatCommandParser<NewArgument>(cChatCommandParser<>(std::move(*thi...
                                               ^
ui/graphical/game/control/chatcommand/chatcommand.h:27:7: note: 
      template is declared here
class cChatCommandParser;
  ^
```

chatcommand.h:

```
...
template<typename... Arguments>
class cChatCommandParser;
...
class cChatCommand
{
public:
    ...
    template<typename NewArgument, typename... Args>
    cChatCommandParser<NewArgument> addArgument(Args&&... args);
    ...
};
template<typename NewArgument, typename... Args>
cChatCommandParser<NewArgument> cChatCommand::addArgument(Args&&... args)
{
    return cChatCommandParser<NewArgument>(cChatCommandParser<>(std::move(*this)), NewArgument(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

The obvious solution would be to `#include chatcommandparser.h`. Unfortunately chatcommandparser.h already includes chatcommand.h.

What is the most conservative way to untangle this? I don't really know what this code is doing and just want to compile it.

Note that GNUs gcc compiles this without a problem. I'm trying to compile this with Apples gcc.

Comment: Why does `chatcommandparser.h` include `chatcommand.h`? Can you work with forward declarations on that end maybe?

Comment: I think not. The class cChatCommandParser has a variable of type cChatCommand. Not a pointer.

Comment: The quick fix is to add `#include "chatcommandparser.h"` after the complete `class cChatCommand` definition but before the definition of its template methods. This is usually done more cleanly with a separate template implementation file (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774036/why-use-a-tpp-file-when-implementing-templated-functions-and-classes-defined-i)) but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: Hm.. chatcommand.ccp compiles with that, but now I'm getting the exact same error when compiling chatcommandparser.cpp.

Comment: Wait wait wait... There are `.cpp` files involved here? I hope you are aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?noredirect=1&lq=1, but at this point you will have to form a [mcve] before anyone can really help you.

Comment: Yes, I read this hours ago. My first try actually was to move the definition in the .cpp file, which lead to problems later for reasons explained in the question you linked.

Comment: Why is it surprising that there are .cpp files involved? I assumed this goes without saying.

Comment: It is surprising because everything you showed so far must be in header files, and the whole problem _stems_ from being unable to use a .cpp for the template definitions (as you found out yourself). Again, there's no way we can help you unless you give us a minimal piece of code that reproduces the error and is representative of your issue.