# How to organize C++ directory with template files, and how to deal with #include calls between files

Tags: c++, templates, makefile, organization

I have some software in C++ which uses both regular and template functions, and I wish to organize my directories properly. To implement this, I followed the guidelines of [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) and wrote header files (.hpp), files with regular functions (.cpp) and files with template functions (.tpp). However, my current directory is poorly organized, like so

```
/
-include/
-src/
--foo.cpp
--foo.hpp
--foo.tpp
--bar.cpp
--bar.hpp
--bar.tpp
--mysoft.cpp
--mysoft.hpp
-Makefile
-mysoft.o
```

where mysoft.hpp is my main file which contains `#include "foo.cpp"` and `#include "bar.cpp"`.

I have a two questions regarding the improvement of this implementation:

1. How would I organize my software tree if I wanted to move files to an include/ folder and not have them all in src/? Should I put both .hpp and .tpp files in include/, or keep the .tpp files in src/?
2. How do I deal with the #include calls between source, header and template files if some files are in inc/?

Here are examples of typical files `foo.cpp`, `foo.hpp` and `foo.tpp`.

```
// foo.cpp
#ifndef FOO_CPP
#define FOO_CPP

#include <somelibrary>
#include "foo.hpp"

void foo_f() {
  // some function
}
```

```
// foo.hpp
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

void foo_f();

template<class T> class fooclass {
  private:
    int var;
  public:
    void foo_g();
}

#include "foo.tpp"
```

```
// foo.tpp
#ifndef FOO_TPP
#define FOO_TPP

template<class T>
void fooclass<T>::foo_g() {
  // some other function
}
```

Comment: For this particular kind of bikeshed, I like the [Pitchfork Layout](https://api.csswg.org/bikeshed/?force=1&url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vector-of-bool/pitchfork/spec/data/spec.bs), which was heavily influenced by Lakos's **Large-Scale C++ Software Design**, Chapter 4: Physical Hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Reading through this link, I could not find anything about the placement of the .tpp file if I should choose the Separate Header Placement solution, and also about my other two questions. Any ideas?

Comment: This is strongly opinion based.  Since `*.tpp` files are included, I'd put them in the same location as the other `*.hpp` header files.  I like my private or internal header files to be kept together with the other source files, and the public or external header files to be kept in a separate location (such as `/include`).  My compiler uses a `-Iincludepath` flag to use a specific include directory (but that is not specified by the C++ standard, its a compiler implementation detail).  I have the `*.o` file go into their own interim build file location.

Comment: In over 15 years of C++ I've never seen anyone make a difference between header files and "template files". Why are you doing this? edit: found this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44774036/1116364

Comment: @DanielJour: With a similar amount of experience, I've never seen it before either. And having followed that link, I still can't see any good reason to do it.

Comment: @Eljay I have a not really settled or answered question over there about a related question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/407056/the-case-against-path-expressions-in-include-directives BTW: it seems that, as this question here will need an opinion-based answer, Softwareengineering.Stackexchange would be better suited for this also.

Comment: @Beta may I turn your eye on this very interesting ;) question also? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/407056/the-case-against-path-expressions-in-include-directives

Comment: @Vroomfondel: Very interesting indeed. Please see my comment on besc's answer.