# Implementing operator<< in C++ template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend, function-declaration

I am having a compiler error implementing operator<< on a C++ template class.  Here is the code:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//a template class to process a pair of "things"
template <typename T>
class Pair
{
private:
    T first;
    T second;

public:
    Pair();
    Pair(T, T);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Pair);  //also tried Pair<T>
};

template <typename T>
Pair<T>::Pair()
{ }

template <typename T>
Pair<T>::Pair(T one, T two)
{
    first = one;
    second = two;
}

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Pair<T> other)
{
    out << "{ " << other.first << " and " << other.second << " }";
    return out;
}

//test code
int main(){
    Pair<string> words("red", "apple");
    cout << "words is " << words << endl;
}
```

I am getting linker error

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@V?$Pair@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Comment: @super: Why would that answer it? It's fine to have templates in a source file if you know what you're doing. There's nothing magical about having templates in headers.

Comment: You need to add an [explicit template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933056/how-do-i-explicitly-instantiate-a-template-function) for the `string` version of your templated `operator <<`.

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Comment: @Bathsheba It wasn't this time, but it's usually the dupe for templates and unresolved external symbol. Didn't read all that carefully apparently.

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake in class definition.

```cpp
template <typename T>
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Pair<T>);
```

I always forget that!

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that you declared a non-template friend function but does not define it for the template argument `std::string` of the class template `Pair`.

To avoid defining the function for different template arguments of the class template `Pair` you should define it within the class definition. In this case the compiler itself will define the function for various template arguments of the class template `Pair` when such a non-template friend function will be required.

The function can be declared and defined as it is shown in the demonstration program below.

Here is the demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Pair
{
private:
    T first;
    T second;

public:
    Pair();
    Pair( const T &, const T & );
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &out, const Pair<T> &other )
    {
        return out << "{ " << other.first << " and " << other.second << " }";
    }
};

template <typename T>
Pair<T>::Pair() : first(), second()
{ }

template <typename T>
Pair<T>::Pair( const T &one, const T &two ) : first( one ), second( two )
{
}

int main()
{
    Pair<std::string> p( "first", "second" );

    std::cout << p << '\n';
    std::cout << Pair<int>() << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
{ first and second }
{ 0 and 0 }
```